# Can I use Home Sharing with an iPod Nano 7th gen?

Tags: itunes, ipod, home-sharing, ipod-nano

I'm considering buying an iPod Nano 7th generation, but I want to be very sure Home Sharing will work with my iMac (OS X El Capitan) with iTunes 12.5 before I purchase one.

Can you tell me if this will work?

Answer (score 1):

The iPod nano 7th generation does not have Wi-Fi, so Home Sharing is not available.